# Converting MTS to MP4 gives strange artefacts

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, conversion, h.264

I am converting video taken with various personal cameras in .MTS format to mp4 in order to reduce the file size. I am getting some strange artefacts and I wonder what simple mistake I am making?

ffmpeg finds this content in the infile:
Program 1
Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080

I used:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.MTS -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -r 25 -b 8M outfile.mp4
```

I set the frame rate in order to keep the original frame rate, otherwise I get 50 fps, but even at 50 fps the artefacts are there.

See attached screen grab (a small crop) for the artefacts, followed by the original.
[image: Artefacts:crop]
[image: No artefacts]

Comment: The source is interlaced. Deinterlace it by adding `-vf yadif`

Comment: That was it! Thanks @Gyan!